# AOSP Downloading and Moving the android source code

Tags: android, android-source

I have a slow & erroneous Internet connection which disconnects now & then.

So I like to know, if there is a way to download the android source directly rather than
repo sync

Or If I download the source in another machine, how can I configure/setup in my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repo sync` is the officially supported method of getting Android sources. You can do `repo sync` on another machine and move the source to your development machine, there should be no special setup necessary for doing so, just copy the files downloaded by `repo` to your development machine (take care to copy all the hidden/dot files as well).

Comment: Thanks. But Let me know if there is any unofficial method for dwld. I am stuck at the prebuilt folder it is probably 1GB on its own.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the technique that Lie Ryan mentioned to get it to one machine F via a reliable Internet connection first. After that, you could consider using a tool such as [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) on the machine S with the slower/unreliable connection to keep the entire project tree between F & S in sync (I believe rsync supports resumption automagically, though I have never tested this).

Hope this helps.

Comment: repo sync also supports resuming. But the problem was almost 1GB prebuilt. however I am not sure if rsync supports this mid-file resuming!